# React Native images with dynamic names

Tags: image, react-native

This works no problem:

```
<Image source={require('./images/ace.png')} />
```

But this:

```
var name = 'ace';

<Image source={require('./images/' + name + '.png')} />
```

I've tried all kinds of variations but it always returns the error:

Requiring unknown module "./images/ace.png". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager.

Comment: I found this way works var name = require('./images/ace.png');
<Image source={name} />
But it still doesn't solve the problem because you just can't concatenate anything or it throws that same error. Seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 5):

As per react native docs,

```
// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />

// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active ? require('./my-icon-active.png') : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />
```

How about pre-declaring what is required and use it conditionally?

Answer (score 1):

Try using url

```
<Image
    style={styles.img}
    resizeMode={'contain'}
    source={{uri: imageURL}}>
```

and in imageURL which might be an URL

for example

```
var imageURL = 'http://assets22.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/702.png'
```

Comment: What about for local images though since this is an app. If I just have an image at './images/ace.png/ the uri command doesn't seem to work. It doesn't throw any error but it just doesn't display the image.

Comment: If you develop for iOS you can use the assets name from xcassets as uri (e.g.: source={{ uri: 'cuteCat' + counter }} )

Comment: That way doesn't work anymore. Check here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#content

Answer (score -1):

Nowadays solution, component named Row:

```
const Row = (props) => {
  let employmentType;

  // Set my own image component dynamically
  if(props.SOME_CONDITION){
     employmentType = <Image source={require('image!Driver')} style={styles.employeeLogo} />
  }
  else{
     employmentType = <Image source={require('image!ANOTHERIMAGE')} style={styles.employeeLogo} />
  }

  return(
    <View style={styles.row_container} elevation={2}>

      {employmentType}
      <Text style={styles.row_text}>{'../Assets/Images/' + props.PictureUrl + '.png'}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.row_text}>{props.Fullname}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.row_text}>{props.EmploymentType}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```